Increasing bandwidth of high speed photodiode amplifier
I'm working on a high-speed photodiode amplifier based on the Texas Instruments LMH6609 VFB op amp. The amplifier should easily handle >20MHz signals, but I'm having trouble actually observing this in my prototypes, as the amplifier's bandwidth seems to be limited to a few MHz.
The photodiode I am using is a BPV10NF from Vishay, with a diode capacitance of about 3pF at 5-10V of reverse bias.
Pictured below are the schematic and PCB layout of the amplifier board:



To test the bandwidth I've been using a simple arrangement of an IR LED and 50 ohm resistor.
I've also attached the script I use to estimate the bandwidth of transimpedance amplifiers (I have checked its results with the ones provided by the Photodiode Circuit Design Wizard
from Analog Devices).
TIA Bandwidth calculator
In my mind there are two possible explanations for the reduced bandwidth:

The LED circuit is more limited than my initial measurements and simulations would indicate. (mildly bad)
The VFB op amp is not capable of providing the necessary gain at the required working frequencies. (very very bad)

Below I've attached the schematic of the LED tester I've used.

And pictures of the optical transmitter are provided here.
Is there anything wrong with my selection of components or my PCB layout?
Datasheets:

LMH6609
BPV10NF

Gerbers:

Manufacturing files for the amplifier PCB


Please add the LED circuit, including layout or photos of the prototype assembly. It may be harder to drive a LED into 100% modulation. I’d start with 10% modulation - led driven through a 50 ohm resistor from a signal generator, and a bias tee, so that the fairly large DC current can be also provided. The LED most likely will need to be driven at least at 50% rated current to maintain rated speed.

The layout looks well done. A little bit more space between the PD pads and ground plane wouldn’t be a bad idea though. I doubt it would change the bandwidth as much as you’re seeing. I’ve put together PD preamps of comparable bandwidth with through-hole components assembled mostly in air, as they were for temporary use…

I've linked to pictures of the LED circuit and added its schematic in the question text. The LED circuit is something I had only built for testing purposes, a scratch build. It should however be working as intended. The idea for it is taken from this ancient application note: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snaa004/snaa004.pdf#page=8

I think it's your LED test circuit. I tried to build something similar using an AWG and found that most of the diodes I had needed to be pulsed at many times their forward voltage to hit the low tens of MHz. Could easily see your circuit maxing out at 5-10 MHz depending on the diodes and how high a voltage you are pulsing. You probably want to get a fast laser diode and driver instead.

Hmm, that may be the case. I know the IR LEDs should be usable up to 20 or so MHz. I was trying to avoid pulsing it (High voltage, avalanche effects etc) and doing something like this: https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Improving-OOK-Modulation-Rate-of-Visible-LED-by-and-Binh-Trong/dbd1b47c013669116ffde1cd47e572708adac46e/figure/2

@user1850479 How did you test the pd amplifier you presented in this stack exchange post: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/383825/transimpedance-amplifier-pcb-layout?rq=1

@Virgil_Tibbs That system was single photon sensitive so I looked at the power spectrum of the shot noise (uniform with frequency). That only works if shot noise is much greater than the amplifier noise though.

Interesting, so something similar to this method: https://www.koheron.com/blog/2017/01/05/detector-response-shot-noise/. Do you think such a method would be applicable to my op amp/photodiode combo?

I've also designed a LNA board (based on the Qorvo AG203-63G) to use for this type of measurement and I'm waiting for the PCBs to be delivered within the week. I could give it a try, though I'm not sure how well it would work :)

I don't think you'll be able to see shot noise above the amplifier noise floor on that system although I didn't analyze the noise carefully so I could be wrong.
